# What do we mean by optimizer.zero_grad()

Tags: deep-learning, optimization

This should be a simple question. But it is vague to me. What do we mean by optimizer.zero_grad(). Consider SGD as an example: $W^{t+1}= W^{t}- \lambda g_t$. Which one becomes zero for each batch. It should be $g_t$ and not $W^t$. Am I right? Overall, for any optimizer, does it mean all other parameters except for $W^t$ and $W^{t+1}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, $g_t$ is what becomes zero when we invoke `optimizer.zero_grad()`.

After invoking `zero_grad()`, we compute the forward pass and invoke `loss.backward()`, which populates again $g_t$. Finally, we invoke `optimizer.step()`, which updates the weights, i.e. $W^{t+1}=W^{t} - \lambda g_t$ in your example.

We need to invoke `zero_grad()` to prevent `loss.backward()` from *accumulating* the new gradient values with the ones from the previous step.

Note that, each optimizer has its own way to use the gradients to update the weights.

Comment: Also note that not calling `zero_grad()` on each iteration is a common strategy if the optimal batch size is larger than your device memory. It's called `gradient accumulation`. And forgetting to call it at all is a common mistake - that even ml luminaries like Andrej Karpathy make (I think in this video which he corrects - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMj-3S1tku0)